# Bad XML block: header size 328 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

am working on android app on eclipse juno.
I've downloaded an open source code and its giving me following errors.

```
[2013-09-04 16:10:24 - MonyBalance] W/ResourceType( 6160): Bad XML block: header size 280 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:10:24 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:10:24 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:11:44 - MonyBalance] W/ResourceType( 6044): Bad XML block: header size 316 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:11:44 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:11:44 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:13:48 - MonyBalance] W/ResourceType( 4040): Bad XML block: header size 292 or total size 7635032 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:13:48 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:13:48 - MonyBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MonyBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:15:21 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6188): Bad XML block: header size 299 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:15:21 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:15:21 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:17:38 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 3416): Bad XML block: header size 321 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:17:38 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:17:38 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:23:47 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 3408): Bad XML block: header size 314 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:23:47 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:23:47 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:24:02 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6184): Bad XML block: header size 317 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:24:02 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:24:02 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:24:28 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6812): Bad XML block: header size 301 or total size 7702144 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:24:28 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:24:28 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:25:19 - MBalance] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2013-09-04 16:25:31 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6420): Bad XML block: header size 328 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:25:31 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:26:09 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 5172): Bad XML block: header size 314 or total size 6136240 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:26:09 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:27:42 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 5432): Bad XML block: header size 344 or total size 6136240 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:27:42 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:27:46 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 7056): Bad XML block: header size 295 or total size 11968944 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:27:46 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:28:10 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 1068): Bad XML block: header size 293 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:28:10 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:28:10 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:28:38 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6756): Bad XML block: header size 308 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:28:38 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:29:12 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6380): Bad XML block: header size 300 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:29:12 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:30:00 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 6196): Bad XML block: header size 328 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:30:00 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-09-04 16:30:05 - MBalance] W/ResourceType( 3444): Bad XML block: header size 297 or total size 12158592 is larger than data size 0
[2013-09-04 16:30:05 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
[2013-09-04 16:30:05 - MBalance] D:\EclipseWorkspace\MBalance\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
```

I've also set action_settings string and hello_world string in string xml file under value folder but nothin happened.
Please help..
Thanks!
Tashen

Comment: What kind of file did you open? When does this error happens?

Comment: when i build the project these errors arouse.these are two xml files main.xml under menu folder and string.xml file under value folder.